# Statistical implications of quota sampling

Tags: sampling, survey

[This source](https://www.scribbr.com/frequently-asked-questions/difference-quota-and-stratified-sampling/) says the difference between quota sampling and stratified sampling is that the units in each group are drawn in a non-random manner. What are the statistical implications of the fact that units are drawn non-random?

Comment: See Wikipedia on [quota sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quota_sampling) and [convenience sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convenience_sampling).  Not using a sampling frame can lead to unrepresentative bias